# Partial derivatives of a definite integral

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I have the following function which I need to evaluate and differentiate:

$$f(x,y)=\int_x^yg(t)dt$$

Firstly how do I find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ ?

Next, for the evaluation of $g(t)$ - I have to evaluate it numerically as the function is complex.  However would I have to calculate the derivatives using this numerical procedure as well to be consistent with the evaluation?  Or would the analytical derivatives above suffice?

Comment: What about the fundamental theorem of calculus ?

Comment: The Claude Leibovici from SimSci days?  If so, hi Claude this is Adrian from PipePhase/NetOpt days!  Aah- so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ would be -$g(x)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ would be $g(y)$ ?

Comment: Hi Adrian ! Yes, I am the one. Good to meet you again. What are you doing ?

Comment: will pm you - is my interpretation of the FTOC correct above?

Comment: Nice to see two friends meeting on MSE. Btw your interpretation of FTOC is correct.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. To give you an idea, we are speaking about more than 30 years without meeting or speaking ! **Thanks to MSE !!**

Comment: Yes amazing!  Regards my 2nd question - can I use those analytical derivatives to pass back to my Newton solver (given that the function evaluation will be numerical not analytical)?  Will they be compatible?  Or do I need to create a derivative of the numerical scheme?

Comment: While I do not consider myself an expert in numerical analysis, I still think that using the FTOC should give you reasonably accurate answer. But it may be the case (based on specific functions involved) that a numerical approximation to the derivative gives you a better answer. After all the difference quotient $(f(a+h) - f(a-h)) /2h$ sometimes gives a better estimate of $f'(a) $ than the quotient $(f(a+h) - f(a)) /h$ which is used in definition of $f'(a) $.